# "db:local:sync" doesn't work after updating ruby 2.2.2 to 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated ruby version of my rails project from `2.2.2` to `2.3.3`, and the project itself works fine.

But when I tried to pull the database from remote by using `capistrano-db-tasks`, it ends up with a error `env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory` like this:

```
$ bundle exec cap production db:local:sync
Loading local database config
env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

This is my environmentail info:

```
% cat .ruby-version
2.3.3
% ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Where should I set the ruby path for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `app/bin` folder. If you open `bundle` file from `bin` folder, and the first line is `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe`, try replacing it with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

If that doesn't work check `rails` file from the same folder, and do the same like mentioned above.